# Update loanbook by reconciling loan stop dates and staff numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I have  two tables with existing data pulled in from Excel spreadsheets converted to .csv:

table one : loanbook

[image: image of table]

table two : olb

[image: image of table]

`staffno` and `loanstart` columns are similar in both tables. For every `staffno` there can be multiple results in `olb` table.

PROBLEM:
I need to update `loanstop` column in table one (loanbook) with `loanstop` values from table two (`olb`) where `staffno` and `loanstart` are the same.

```
UPDATE loanbook3
SET loanbook3.loanstop = (
    SELECT loanstop
    FROM olb
    WHERE olb.staffno = loanbook3.staffno
    AND
     olb.loanstart = loanbook3.loanstart

);
```

RESULT
 #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

What do I do?

Comment: Why the [excel] tag?

Answer (score 0):

use `limit 1` with your Subquery

```
UPDATE loanbook3 SET loanbook3.loanstop = 
( SELECT loanstop FROM olb WHERE 
olb.staffno = loanbook3.staffno 
AND olb.loanstart = loanbook3.loanstart limit 1)
```